Slang word for 'inactive', 'lazy', 'sleepy',
What is a slang word for "inactive", "lazy", "abnormally slow-thinking"?
Please look at this situation.
A friend (A) is teaching English to his friend (B). B is usually dynamic and cheerful but the class today is going on very badly, B is answering reluctantly, he hardly ever smiles. He looks as if he is obsessed in some unpleasant thoughts. Or maybe just tired. B has to pull out answers from him all the time. Finally A asks him: "Come on, B, wake up, why are you so ________ today? Something happened?"
What slang word may be put in here?

Dozy is a possibility (not slang, but informal).

'Inactive' and 'lazy' could be descriptions of moods or tendencies; 'abnormally slow-thinking' sounds like a disability.

Michael, I meant the person is responding with long delays as if he is thinking about smth although normally s/he isn't like that. The mental condition is fine)

Non-slang is lethargic.

Slang is spaced (out): 2. generally disorientated.

Or "Wake up, sleepy-head".  Wake up, B. Why such a sleepy-head today?

A great slang word for "dull, sluggish" is logy, though it might be the "wrong slang" for your setting; it has strong "Valley girl" connotations.

Zonked
Extremely tired or affected by drugs or alcohol.
Useless
Of no use; not working or not achieving what is needed
Distracted
Nervous or confused because you are worried about something.
Off
Away from a place or position, especially the present place, position, or time.
Fucked
Which means pretty much anything in English but relevantly:
Broken or not working properly OR very tired

@Avidlearner NB, "fuck" is a fairly offensive word, e.g. banned from US public broadcasting. It could be appropriate in some slang contexts but not all. Not recommended to use unless you're sure it's ok with your audience!

@AndyBonner That's despite it being the most useful word in English after "yes" and "no"
